# NSDateFormatter equivalent in Titanium / Convert date in specified format in Titanium

Tags: ios, datetime, titanium, nsdateformatter, titanium-mobile

I'm working with the date and time in my Titanium based iOS application.

My issue is, I'm getting the time in the below format:

```
Wed Jan 16 2013 17:32:40 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I want to change it like:

```
Jan 16, 2013, 05:32 pm
```

In iOS there is **[NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** for doing this.

**What I did :**

1. Currently I'm doing it manually using `split` and switch `cases`, but it fails if the input time format changes, then I need to re-write the code for the changed format.
2. I searched alot in **[Titanium Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api)**, but didn't get any solution.
3. I asked same question on their [forum](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146975/convert-date-in-specified-format), didn't get any reply till now.

Is there is anyway to do this in Titanium?

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any alternatives for the `NSDateFormatter` in Titanium.

I tested the Moment.js, but it didn't worked for my case.

I implemented a JavaScript function for achieving my output.

```
/**
 * Function for formatting the date and time 
 * @param {Object} dateTime 
 */
function formatDateTime(dateTime)
{
    var arr = dateTime.split(' ');
    var convertedDate = arr[1]+' '+arr[2]+', '+arr[3];
    var convertedTime = arr[4];
    var returnValue = convertedDate+', '+convertedTime;
    return returnValue;
}
```

**Edit on 27 Feb 2014**

After facing the JavaScript date formatting issue on different occasions, I finally developed my own JavaScript module, this module will format the JavaScript Date object to Specified formats. You can find it here : [**MMP_DateTime**](https://github.com/Midhun-MP/MMP_DateTime)

Answer (score 1):

Look for moment.js JavaScript module for date formatting

Answer (score 0):

I write one function which will convert date as per my requirement as given below

```
var getRequiredDate = function(date) {
              var monthList = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear(); // Use standard date methods
    var newdate = monthList[month] + ' ' + day + ", " + year;
    Ti.API.info("Date :" + newdate);
```

};

Hope this helps you.